# CTkEntry: How to use place_holder and get the text without textVariable

Tags: python, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

Hey y'all my first post here =0

in the documentation of CTk it says that place holders do not work with text variables. So I chose to no use the text variable, since I want the place holder. But how do I get the text in the widget if there is no parameter 'text', in other words .cget('text') throws an exception.

This is what I'm trying to do to avoid using the text_variable, it throws the excetion saying

```
self.search_bar = ctk.CTkEntry(self.frame_for_top_buttons,
                               width=440,
                               height=31,
                               placeholder_text='Search the Library')

self.search_bar.bind('<Key>',command=lambda key: self.display_books_in_the_library_frame(search_book=self.search_bar.cget('text')))

Exception: ValueError: 'text' is not a supported argument. Look at the documentation for supported arguments.
```

With the text variable it works like this, its fine but I cannot use the place_holder:

```
self.word_to_search = ctk.StringVar(value='')
self.search_bar = ctk.CTkEntry(self.frame_for_top_buttons,
                               width=440,
                               height=31,
                               textvariable=self.word_to_search,
                               placeholder_text='Search the Library')

self.search_bar.bind('<Key>',command=lambda key:
self.display_books_in_the_library_frame(search_book=self.word_to_search.get()))
```

Any solution to get the text and use place_bolder at the same time?

Comment: You just call `.get()` on the Entry instead of the StringVar.